# Error in python while running androguard importing zlib

Tags: python, zlib, androguard

I've been trying to run androguard on Ubuntu 13.10
I have downloaded the `zlib` library and placed it in the correct path
While running the file `apk.py` , which has

```
from zlib import crc32
```

it returns an error saying

```
Cannot import name crc32
```

The `zlib` directory contains a file `crc32.c` and `crc32.h` along with `crc32.o`
How can I fix the import error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete or rename the `zlib` folder - otherwise python might try to import something from there instead of the [stdlib package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) named `zlib`.